# Lowercase 'g' in a string is "happy" if there is another 'g' immediately next to it

Tags: java, string

I need to implement code where lowercase `'g'` in a string is "happy" if there is another `'g'` adjacent to it. Then, return `true` if all the `g's` in the given string are happy. For example:

> gHappy("xxggxx") → true
>   gHappy("xxgxx") → false
>   gHappy("xxggyygxx") → false

Here is the code I tried:

```
public boolean gHappy(String str) {
  if(str.length() < 1){
     return false;
  }

  boolean result = false;
  for(int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
     if(str.charAt(i) == 'g' && str.charAt(i - 1) == 'g' 
     || str.charAt(i + 1) == 'g'){
        result = true;

     }
  }

  return result;
}
```

But Im failing some of the test cases such as:

> gHappy("gg") → should be `true` → getting `false`
>   gHappy("xxgggxyg") → should be `false` → getting `true`

Comment: It might be an operator precedence issue, && vs || but im not sure. Try wrapping the conditions in parentheses. If 1 && (2||3) and see what happens

Comment: Alternatively, invert your logic to immediately return false for any case that fails, else return true.

Comment: Also, 1 is not smaller than 2-1 .

Comment: `str.contains("gg")`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can condition first if the character is `g` then that time you will 
   compare it's previous and next character if both are not 'g' simply make 
   flag variable false and come out of the loop. you have to check one more 
   condition if single 'g' comes at last index of string like "xxgggxyg" then 
   you should check  (i == str.length()-2) && (str.charAt(i+1) == 'g') && 
   (str.charAt(i) != 'g')

```
public boolean gHappy(String str) {
boolean flag = true;
if(str == "") return flag;

if(str.length() <= 2 && !str.equals("gg")) {
return false;
}

for(int i = 1; i < str.length()-1; i++)
{
  if(str.charAt(i) == 'g')
  {
    if(!(str.charAt(i-1) == 'g' || str.charAt(i+1) == 'g'))
    {
      flag = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  else if((i == str.length()-2) && (str.charAt(i+1) == 'g') && 
  (str.charAt(i) != 'g'))
  {
     flag = false;
     break;
  }
  }
  return flag;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Behold, the power of regex!

```
public boolean gHappy(String input) {
    // make sure input matches two g's in a row, but not a lone g
    return input.matches(".*gg.*") && !input.matches(".*(?<!g)g(?!g).*");
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Spq2hd

Answer (score 0):

I'd extract out the idea of what a happy character is, into a function, then loop over all characters calling the check, and bailing out if any are unhappy.

Something like this.

```
boolean isCharcterHappy(String s, int index) {
    if(s.charAt(index)!='g')
      return true;
    if(index>0 && s.charAt(index-1)=='g')
      return true;
    if(index<s.size()-1 && s.charAt(index+1)=='g')
      return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean gHappy(String str) {
  for(int i=0; i<str.size(); ++i) {
   if(!isCharcterHappy(str,i))
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a `gHappy` function which verifies if a given string is happy regarding a certain character.

```
public boolean gHappy(String str, char chr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char cmp = str.charAt(i);

        if(cmp == chr && i < (str.length() - 1) && str.charAt(i+1) == chr)
            // Found the character and the same character is at it's right
            i++; // Little optimization, next character is the same so is automatically surrounded by the character.
        else if(cmp == chr && i > 0 && str.charAt(i-1) == chr) // Not at our right, maybe at our left?
            continue;
        else if(cmp == chr) // Not left nor right, this character is unhappy !
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Notice the little optimization when the same char is found at the right side of the current char. Since when can be sure that char will also be happy (as we are the same char and sitting at his left hand side in the string) we don't need to check it anymore, hence the `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop starts at 1 and ends when i is not less than the length of the string minus 1. (str.length() - 1) So "gg" wouldn't even run the loop.

For "xxgggxyg", when your program sees ggg, your boolean is set true, but you should set it to false once you hit "yg" at the end.

You might want to do like (this && this) || (this && this) and not (this && this) || this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It's a bit clunky, but it only does a loop if it's absolutely necessary. What do you guys think?

```
public boolean gHappy(String str) {
      if (str.indexOf('g') != -1)
      {
        //If string length is three or above
        if (str.length() >= 3)
        {
          //Creates a boolean that we will eventually return, and it starts as true.
          boolean ret = true;
          //Checks the front of the string for unhappy g's
          if (str.charAt(0) == 'g' && str.charAt(1) != 'g')
          {
            return false;
          }
          //Checks the end of the string for unhappy g's
          if (str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'g' && str.charAt(str.length()-2) != 'g')
          {
            return false;
          }
          //Create a while loop that finds out if there are any 'g's that are unhappy in the middle
          int incre = 1;
          //While there is an instance of 'g':
          while (str.indexOf('g', incre) != -1)
          {
            //If there is no g to the left or the right of that g, we return false.
            if (str.charAt(str.indexOf('g', incre) - 1) != 'g' && str.charAt(str.indexOf('g', incre) + 1) != 'g')
            {
              return false;
            }
            //If there is, then we increment our search place by one character, the one after the 'g'.
            else
            {
              incre = str.indexOf('g', incre) + 2;
            }
          }
          return ret;
        }
        else if (str.length() == 2)
        {
          //If both chars are 'g', we know to return true since there are only 2 chars.
          if (str.charAt(0) == 'g' && str.charAt(1) == 'g')
          {
            return true;
          }
          //If we find a 'g', alone, we return false;
          else
          {
            return false;
          }
        }
        //If the character is one character and a g, we return false.
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      //If there is no instance of 'g', we return true.
      else
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose I could do "incre = str.indexOf('g', incre) + 2;", and that would be equally valid because we know that the next 'g' is connected to the previous one, or else the char is not a 'g' anyways. That's what I'll change it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean gHappy(String str)
{

   Boolean flag=true;

   if(str.length()<1){

      return flag;
   }

   if(str.length()==1 || (str.charAt(str.length()-1)=='g' &&
      str.charAt(str.length()-2)!='g')){

      return false;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

   if( i>=0 && i<str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i)=='g' &&
      (str.charAt(i+1)=='g' || str.charAt(i-1)=='g'))
   {
      flag=true;
   }
   else if(i>=0 && i<str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i)=='g'&& (!(str.charAt(i+1)=='g' ||
      str.charAt(i-1)=='g'))){

      flag=false;

   }
}

   return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
public boolean gHappy(String str) {
  int strLength = str.length();
  if(strLength == 1 && str.charAt(0) == 'g') {
    return false;
  }
  if(strLength > 1 && str.charAt(strLength-1) == 'g' && str.charAt(strLength-2) != 'g') {
    return false;
  }
  for(int i=1; i<strLength-1; i++) {
    if(strLength > 2 && str.charAt(i) == 'g' && (str.charAt(i+1) != 'g' && str.charAt(i-1) != 'g')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution: I've use the int count method, and it works fine. The method uses the current "g" in the loop, to find other "g" besides it.

```
public boolean gHappy(String str) {
    int g = 0;
    int happy = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.substring(i, i+1).equals("g")) { // finds the current "g"
        g++; // adds all "g" in the str
        if (i < str.length()-1 && str.substring(i+1, i+2).equals("g")) {
          happy++; // adds happy, when another g is after the current "g"
        } else if (i > 0 && str.substring(i-1, i).equals("g")) {
          happy++; // adds happy, when g is detected before the current "g"
        }
      }
    }
    return (g==happy); // return true if all g is happy
}
```