# How to check if all lowercase 'g' in a string has another 'g' adjacent to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that returns True/False based on the following conditions:

- A lowercase 'g' in a string is "happy" if there is another 'g' adjacent to it, such as "gg". Then, return `True` if all the g's in the given string are happy.
- Else, return `False`

The desired output is:

```
string: xggt
output: True

string: abgsx
output: False

string: xxggygxx
output: False
```

I am a little lost with this question and am scratching my head at trying to solve it. Would anyone be able to assist me and explain how the desired result is achieved?

My current code is :

```
s=input("Enter string: ")

happy = true
sad = false
while s <='g':
    print ("Happy?",sad)
elif s <='gg':
    print("Happy?", happy)
```

Comment: If you can read Java, there's a same question but all the answers are in Java: [Lowercase 'g' in a string is "happy" if there is another 'g' immediately next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32107810/2745495)

Comment: Hi Gino, i saw that earlier but thought it would be a bit hard to convert from java to python since I'm fairly new to learning  python

Comment: to be honest this seems like a coding challenge - but in any case this code does not seem like it would work.

Comment: If _you_ had to do this (instead of writing a program) what steps would you follow? You should make a flowchart of these steps. _Then_ translate it to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions can be a little hard to read and understand, but is more efficient. This is an implementation that searches for instances of the letter `g` and then looks for a preceding or following `g`. If not found, then return unhappy result:

```
s = input("Enter string: ")
happy = True
for ctr, letter in enumerate(s):
    if letter == "g":
        if ctr > 0 and s[ctr - 1] == "g":
            pass
        elif ctr < (len(s) - 1) and s[ctr + 1] == "g":
            pass
        else:
            # unhappy
            happy = False
            break
print(s, happy)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library is very helpful when looking for patterns in strings.
So in that case you would want to search for one of the following patters:

- "g"
- "...Xg"
- "gX..."
- "...XgX..."

where X is anything except 'g'.
so with re library it would be:

```
import re
s=input("Enter string: ")
res = not bool(re.search(r"(^g$|[^g]g$|^g[^g]|[^g]g[^g])", s))
print("Happy?", res)
```

Comment: I thing this regex find 'not happy' strings, i.e., detects if exist single 'g', so should be *`not res`*. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The classic way of doing this would be with a regex, but I'll show how to do it with `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def is_happy(s):
...     """Returns whether all 'g's are next to at least one other 'g'."""
...     return all(sum(1 for _ in x) > 1 for g, x in groupby(s, "g".__eq__) if g)
...
>>> is_happy("xggt")
True
>>> is_happy("abgsx")
False
>>> is_happy("xxggygxx")
False
```

Let's break down the individual pieces:

```
for g, x in groupby(s, "g".__eq__)
```

`groupby` turns an iterable (in this case `s`) into "groups" based on a grouping function.

`g` in this iteration is the result of `"g".__eq__`, i.e. whether the group is of `g`s or not.  `x` is the actual group (i.e. a substring of `s`).

```
if g
```

The `if g` on the end means we'll skip any `g, x` pair where `g` is false (i.e. any group that's not just `g`s).

```
sum(1 for _ in x) > 1
```

This tells us whether the group has more than one element.  If `x` were a string we could just use its `len`, but it's a `_grouper` which is a one-use iterable that doesn't implement `__len__`, so instead we use `sum` to iterate over it and count 1 for each character.

```
all(...)
```

tells us whether all of the elements in the iteration are true -- are *all* the `g` groups longer than 1 element?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it by checking the index before and after every "g" in a word.

```py
my_inputs = ["xggt", "abgsx", "xxggygxx"]

for _input in my_inputs:
    state = False
    for i, char in enumerate(_input):
        if char == "g":
            if i > 0 and _input[i-1] == "g" or i < len(_input)-1 and _input[i+1] == "g":
                state = True
            else:
                state = False
    print(f"string: {_input}\noutput: {state}\n")
```

output:

```
string: xggt
output: True

string: abgsx
output: False

string: xxggygxx
output: False
```

Comment: This solution throws an `IndexError` for input string "gxg".

Comment: @Brian fixed now.